# I want to delete seed and insert specific hex key with input

Tags: python-3.x, hex, bitcoin

I want to delete seed and insert specific hex key with input

import hashlib
import random
import time
import base58
from .util import doublehash256

class Key:

```
def __init__(self, seed=None):
    self.hash = ''
    self.hashdigest = ''
    self.hex = ''
    self.wif = ''
    self.wif_c = ''

def _seed(self):
    t = int(time.time())
    return str(random.getrandbits(3000) - t)

def generate(self, seed=None):
    self._generate_raw(seed)
    self._generate_hex()
    self._generate_wif()

    return {'hex': self.hex, 'wif': self.wif, 'wifc': self.wif_c}

def _generate_raw(self, seed=None):
    if (seed == None): seed = self._seed()
    self.hash = hashlib.sha256(seed.encode())
    self.hashdigest = self.hash.digest()

def _generate_hex(self):
    self.hex = self.hash.hexdigest()

def _generate_wif(self):
    prefix = b'\x80'
    suffix = b'\x01'

    d = prefix + self.hashdigest

    checksum = doublehash256(d).digest()[:4]
    checksum_c = doublehash256(d + suffix).digest()[:4]

    self.wif = base58.b58encode(d + checksum).decode('utf-8')
    self.wif_c = base58.b58encode(d + suffix + checksum_c).decode('utf-8')

def __str__(self):
    return """Private Key HEX: %s
            \rPrivate Key WIF: %s\r
            \rPrivate Key WIF compressed: %s 
            """ % (self.hex, self.wif, self.wif_c)
```

[image: first]

like this one

[image: another]

Comment: Please try to add image here in Stackoverflow, instead of external site

Comment: [Edit] your post to change textual output to *text* (formatted as `code`), not as images. Also – while you are doing that –, there is no real question here.